# Shared Library QT Resource

Tags: c++, qt, resources, shared

Im having again another problem. This time, I have a .dll, a shared library that contains a .qrc (QT Resource) file, the problem is, that when I'm trying to access one of the resources of the library, it doesn't work.
I tried implementing the:

```
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resourcefilename)
```

and it stills not working.
(It says that the "qInitResources_resourcefilename()" is not found.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the solution.
The qInitResources_name() was not found. So, I created a function inside the shared library

```
int RmiLib::startResources(){
    extern int qInitResources_rmi();
    return qInitResources_rmi();
}
```

Then, on the main App, I called that function, and yay! It worked.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that you are using Windows because you say you have a .dll

I just ran into this same problem that the function qInitResources_resourcefilename cannot be found. This function does indeed exist in the shared library if your library has a .qrc file (check the mapfile). The problem is that this function is not exported and so the linker does not find it while linking the main App. I added the function qInitResources_resourcefilename to the export table of the shared library as follows.

Add a new file to the shared library
**export.def**

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
  qInitResources_resourcefilename
```

Add the following to your shared library .pro file

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /DEF:\"$${PWD}\\export.def\"
OTHER_FILES += \
    export.def
```

Your solution works around this problem because RmiLib::startResources is included in the export table.

I am using Windows 7, MSVC 2010, Qt 5.2.0